# Ajax call in for loop wait until ALL done (error or success)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I am making AJAX calls in a `for` loop and I would like to wait until all of them are done before doing something.

I am trying to use promises but there is something that I'm missing because it won't work. If an error is fired, my `when` call is fired immediately and I don't want to. I want to wait until ALL calls are done, no matter if it's success or error.

When all calls are done, I want the number of entries that succeeded and an array of errors.

Here is my code :

```
for (var i = 0; i < resp.propertiesList.length; i++) {
    var documentToSend = { 
        indexName: indexName, 
        type: type, 
        jsonContent: blabla 
    };

    var promise = _TOOLS.Ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: urlTest,
        data: documentToSend,
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (dataResponse) {
            numberOfEntriesSuccess++;
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, errorThrown) {
            var errorResponse = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            errorsList.push(errorResponse.ExceptionMessage + ". Skipping line.");
        }
    });

    promises.push(promise);
}

//When all ajax calls are finished, load report page and display informations
$.when.apply($, promises).done(function() { 
    console.log("DONE " + promises.length); 
    console.log(errorsList); 
})
```

I tried with `.done`, `.then`, `.always`, but none of them fire when I wish to.
I read a lot about promises on the internet but I'm definitely missing something and it's driving me crazy.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: This is (rather unfortunately) how `when()` works - ie. as soon as 1 request fails it immediately jumps to the error handler and halts processing of further requests. The only real alternative is to prototype/create an alternate version of `$.when` from the jQuery source which silently fails on errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I find easiest to handle these things is keeping track of the status of each of the Async calls in an object or array. Each time a call completes, flag it as done and check if there are any more running. You could even just add a boolean to your object to check if `asyncIsBusy`, or a property for `ajaxStatus`.

I am assuming here that `indexName` and `type`are coming from `resp.propertiesList`(you don't seem to use your `i`anywhere, so I guess you left that out by accident?).

```
for (var i = 0; i < resp.propertiesList.length; i++) {
    var documentToSend = { 
        indexName: indexName, 
        type: type, 
        jsonContent: blabla 
    };

    sendDocumentAjax(resp.propertiesList[i], documentToSend)
}

function sendDocumentAjax(listObj, documentData){
    listObj.ajaxStatus = 'pending';
    _TOOLS.Ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: urlTest,
        data: documentData,
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (dataResponse) {
            listObj.ajaxStatus = 'success';
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, errorThrown) {
            var errorResponse = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            listObj.ajaxStatus = 'error: '+ errorResponse;
        }
        always: checkAjaxStatuses;
    });
}

function checkAjaxStatuses(){
    var pending = [];
    var successes = [];
    var errors = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < resp.propertiesList.length; i++) {
        if(resp.propertiesList[i].ajaxStatus === 'pending'){
            pending.push(resp.propertiesList[i]);
        }
        if(resp.propertiesList[i].ajaxStatus === 'success'){
            successes.push(resp.propertiesList[i]);
        }
        if(resp.propertiesList[i].ajaxStatus.indexOf('error') !== -1){
            errors.push(resp.propertiesList[i]);
        }
    }

    console.log('ajax completed.');
    console.log(pending.length + ' pending.');
    console.log(successes.length + ' succeeded.');
    console.log(errors.length + ' failed.');
}
```

Note how I used a separate function to send the ajax, so a new closure is created for each object that you sent an ajax call for. You can't do all of this through anonymous functions because `i` would always be the maximum value in the callbacks (since the loop finishes before any ajax call is completed), leaving you no way to reference the original object you sent the Ajax for. Using a separate function circumvents this issue.

Comment: Yes sorry I left out some things by accident. Thanks I will try this, it seems a good idea

Comment: no problem, the intentions were clear enough :) Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

`Q.allSettled` can help you on this, you may find the npm package here - https://www.npmjs.com/package/q.

Answer (score 1):

Go for a recursive approach:

```
ajaxLoopArray(myArray, function(){ /* do something when finish */ });

function ajaxLoopArray(someArray, callbackFunction){
    if(someArray.length>0){ //condition to break the loop
        data = someArrapy.pop(); // pop removes the last element from an array and returns that element.
        $.ajax({
            data
        }).done(function(x){
            //success
        })
        .fail(function(){
            //catch the error here
        })
        .always(function(){
            ajaxLoopArray(someArray, callbackFunction); //recursive call: keep on looping independently of success or error
        });
    }else{
        callbackFunction(); //when everything was done
    }
}
```

Comment: This would send the ajax requests one by one, a new one each time the previous one completed. It would work but it would not be very efficient compared to sending them all at once and handling them in whichever order they come back.

Answer (score 0):

try setting async: false in ajax call

```
var promise = _TOOLS.Ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: urlTest,
                    data: documentToSend,
                    async: false,
                    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (dataResponse) {
                              numberOfEntriesSuccess++;
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, errorThrown) {
                               var errorResponse = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                                errorsList.push(errorResponse.ExceptionMessage + ". Skipping line.");
                    }
                });
```

Comment: NO. `async: false` 1) won't make any difference to the problem 2) Is ***incredibly*** bad practice.

Comment: +1 to Rory. whats the point of AJAX if you are killing your entire page while it runs? Use a loading cursor/image/... if the user needs to wait for some things to finish before data is displayed.